# Inventory Turnover Estimation

Tags: estimation, censoring

I have an inventory of real estate. Every period I am acquiring some new inventory and selling some items from the inventory. I would like to estimate the average waiting time it takes to sell an asset from the time I purchase.

The problem is that I only know how many periods it took to sell those assets I managed to sell, but only know that waiting time is at least some value T(i) for those that I couldn't, where i is the asset index.

I cannot simply take average of all waiting times since it will underestimate the average due to the fact that I do not know the exact waiting time for those that I couldn't yet sell.

What kind of distribution should I consider and most importantly what kind of estimation procedure should be employed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [Survival Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). In medical settings, you have a group of "patients" and you observe them over time, recording when some event occurs (e.g., death, heart attack, etc). However, since studies are often much shorter than a human's lifespan, the experimental data is "censored" since we don't know when the surviving patients will die, and how that would have affected our estimates.

In your case, your "patients" are houses, and the "event" is a sale. Right now, your sample is censored, since not all houses have sold.

One approach would be to calculate the [Kaplan-Meier Estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator) of the Survival Function. This "estimator" is a step-function that approximates the probability of a house being sold after a certain time on the market. However, it can only be calculated using the houses you've sold, so it will not go out far enough in time (e.g., it will stop at, say, $P(T>20)=0.1$). To extrapolate beyond this, you need to assume some sort of model.

a natural model for your case might be to assume that home sales occur randomly, but at some average rate. In this case, you'd fit an exponential distribution to your Kaplan-Meiter estimate of the survival function (this is not too bad since the survival function is just $1-F(t)$ and $F(T)=1-e^{-\lambda*T}$, where you are fitting the function to the calculated points of the survival curve.

The only wrinkle here is that you are not starting your "cohort" of homes at the same time. Now, if we assume an exponentially distributed time to sale, this will not be a problem, due to the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution. In your case, you would just use "days on market" as the variable, and then *when* they started is irrelevant, just how long they've been sitting.

Comment: Exponential distribution is probably not a good assumption because I don't expect the highest point of the density to be at point 0. Basically it is unlikely to sell the real estate immediately.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc .... depends on how hot the market it...one of my own homes sold (like offered and agreed to a contract) in less than 4 hours.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc however, I see your point...there are numerous other distributions one can use. Exponential is just simple to interpret and it jives with the idea of *a* turnover rate

Comment: Weibull and gamma distributions are probably the two most common generalizations of the exponential distribution that are used in survival analysis.

Comment: @CliffAB thanks (+1). Yes, either of those are great, and both assume that the sales rate starts low, increases, then decreases, so may be much  more realistic.